# unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9ccc8886a0

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I recently started learning to code in Swift to get the practice and experience to build the app for my startup. Any who, I am having trouble with the current failure instance noted in the title.

This pertaining to this specific line of code.

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(CitySelector: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
return dataSource.count
}
```

Alternatively, I had it initially set the return value to 1, but the same problem existed.

The problem began happening when I set the dataSource and delegate to "view".

I am at a lose of where to go with this error as I can not determine where the actual issue lies. I've followed various tutorials to the "t" as well as consulted the Swift developer pages. What am I missing in this to cause the error?

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Try setting the delegate to "self" not to "view"

Comment: your view does not implement the method therefore crash

Answer (score 1):

Your picker view is expecting its delegate and dataSource to provide some specific functions.

When you set your delegate to "view" and then ask it (the view) to return a value from a function related to a picker view, it says "I don't know what you are asking me to do, because I'm not designed to handle that."  Which is basic speak for "unrecognized selector sent to instance."

You need to set your class to conform to UIPickerViewDelegate, then set your delegate to self.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the problem by setting the "delegate" and "dataSource" to *ViewController* instead of *View*.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your Class in Interface Builder/Xib to be `YourCustomViewController` instead of regular `UIViewController` for your View in Storyboard (if you're using Storyboard)?